# Resolve breaks between JS encodeURI and ASP Server.URLEncode

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, urlencode, url-encoding

Until now I foolishly thought JavaScript's `encodeURI()` would produce the same results as ASP classic's `Server.URLEncode()`.  Here's an example where that fails:

```
encodeURI("戦艦帝国") = "%E6%88%A6%E8%89%A6%E5%B8%9D%E5%9B%BD"
Server.URLEncode("戦艦帝国") = "%C6%88%A6%C8%89%A6%C5%B8%9D%C5%9B%BD"
```

Since I'm in a system that uses both languages, is there any encoding method in one that is guaranteed to produce the same encoding as a method in the other?

---

<sub>(Note: `Server.UrlEncode(str)` is supposedly equivalent to `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str, Response.ContentEncoding)`)</sub>

Comment: I tried to convert the result, but the javascript one seems wrong.
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: @Vixed - Both that tool and [this tool](http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode) match the javascript value (i.e., the one beginning `%E6`).  Probably because they're using javascript....

Comment: **<%=server.UrlEncode("戦艦帝国")%>** returns **%E6%88%A6%E8%89%A6%E5%B8%9D%E5%9B%BD** I think it's just a question of charset.

Comment: @Vixed - You're right!  My ASP page is getting the string from an MS SQL database.  It displays it correctly (as pasted here), but there must be something else tagging along with the string value that produces the different encoding in that scenario.  Digging back in now.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, but be sure to save using UTF-8

```
<%Response.charset="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
  <body>
    <%=Server.UrlEncode("戦艦帝国")%>
    <br />
    <script>document.write(encodeURI("戦艦帝国"))</script>
  </body>
</html>
```